# Angular 4 mat-tab delete tab

Tags: angular, tabs

How do i delete a dynamic tab in Angular 4? Here is the code that I have tried

```
<mat-tab *ngFor="let thisTab of tabs" label={{thisTab}} class="close-thik">

</mat-tab>
```

**CSS**

/* Close Button */

```
[class*='close-'] {
  color: #777;
  font: 14px/100% arial, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  top: 5px;
}

.close-classic:after {
  content: 'X'; /* ANSI X letter */
}

.close-thin:after {
  content: '×'; /* UTF-8 symbol */
}

.close-thik:after {
  content: '✖'; /* UTF-8 symbol */
}

/* Dialog */

.dialog {
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;

}

/* Container */

.container {
  width: 576px; margin: 0 auto;
}

.container:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Couldn't achieve the close button on the tab.Is there a standard way to do this via CSS? or Angular itself has some specifications for the same?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this by simply remove element from array :

**Component Side :**

```
tabs = [
    { label : 'Tab1' , content : 'Content1'},
    { label : 'Tab2' , content : 'Content2'},
    { label : 'Tab3' , content : 'Content3'},
    { label : 'Tab4' , content : 'Content4'},
    { label : 'Tab5' , content : 'Content5'},
]

removeMe(i){
    this.tabs.splice(i, 1);
}
```

**Template Side :**

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab *ngFor='let tab of tabs;let i = index;' label="{{tab.label}}"> 
    {{tab.content}}
    <button (click)='removeMe(i)'>Remove</button>
  </mat-tab>

</mat-tab-group>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tab-remove)**

Comment: This model works, I have tried the same earlier too. still looking to achieve something like below.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fwCUChIfXPDzkR2n21Co1fOh1CPVpxgZ

Comment: That will also work , you just need to position that in tab title ,

Comment: I see one more issue with this. If there is a disabled tab towards the right of the tab you are currently closing, that tab gets selected, though it is disabled